# problem with using git using private key

Tags: ssh, git, clone, github

sorry if this question seems so easy but I'm new with UBUNTU and I still couldn't figure that out.

I've been given a private key with password to clone and install a software from a repository using git (`git clone ssh://gitolite3@git.[Rest]...`) but unfortunately every time I try to have access to that folder it gives me "permission denied" (this is a experimental software for an academic project) , I'm over SSH and I've also put the private key in .ssh folder but I still get this message.
can you please help me and explain me a little bit about how does git works with this private key and what should I do to solve this problem and clone it successfully?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: I suspect you're accessing the repository over HTTPS, rather than over SSH in your clone command. Please [edit] your question to include *full* command & output you see in your terminal, so we can help you better.

Comment: I just made a mistake while I was typing the command, it's fixed by now. I'm connected to a remote machine via SSH and trying to clone and install this software on that machine, this is the command:
git clone ssh://gitolite3@git.[nameOfTheRepo]...
and I get this message:
"Permission denied, please try again."

Comment: You are asking to log in as the user "gitolite3".  Is this really the user name the server admin assigned you?

Comment: yes, this user is added already and I've been provided with only this private key to have access and pull this repo, but I don't know how to do it honestly...

Comment: I found the solution! based on this post:
http://superuser.com/questions/232362/how-to-convert-ppk-key-to-openssh-key-under-linux

Thanks guys :)

Comment: @SinaSh feel free to add your solution as an answer below and mark it as your preferred solution

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions for the keys inside the .ssh folder
Your private key should be protected:

Make sure your private key has permissions like `{r-x------}`

If not just do this by running `chmod 600 id_rsa`

Comment: -1 How do you come up with the idea that it is a permissions problem?

Comment: Dunno how did he/she decide that but it was exactly the issue in my case...